# module "Qt3D.Core" is not installed

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt3d

I am trying to add 3D capabilities to my existing Qt application. In my `project.pro` file I set the QT variable:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
QT += 3dcore 3drender 3dinput 3dquick qml quick 3dquickextras
SUBDIRS = plugins/datasource \
          plugins/screenManager

qml.files = apps modules sysui i18n am-config.yaml Main*.qml
INSTALLS += qml
```

**Edit:** I set the `QML_IMPORT_TRACE` environment variable to `1`. Now I see the following when I attempt run the app:

```
[DBG  | default] QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml"                                                                    [:0]
[DBG  | default] QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "/usr/local/Qt-5.7.0/include"                                                                          [:0]
[DBG  | default] QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "/usr/local/bin"       [:0]
[DBG  | default] QQmlImportDatabase::setImportPathList: ("/usr/local/bin", "/usr/local/Qt-5.7.0/include", "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml", "/home/aras/Projects/UI/imports/shared", "/home/aras/Projects/UI/imports/system") [:0]
[CRIT | am.system] WARNING: could not register service org.freedesktop.Notifications on D-Bus (unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-c9i1pNpEVT):                        [:0]
[DBG  | default] QQmlImports(file:///home/aras/Projects/UI/Main.qml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick" 2.5 as "QQ2"                                        [:0]
[DBG  | default] QQmlImports(file:///home/aras/Projects/UI/Main.qml)::importExtension: loaded "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick.2/qmldir"    [:0]
[DBG  | default] QQmlImportDatabase::registerPluginTypes: "QtQuick" from "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick.2"                                     [:0]
[DBG  | default] QQmlImports(file:///home/aras/Projects/UI/Main.qml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick.Window" 2.2 as ""                                    [:0]
[DBG  | default] QQmlImports(file:///home/aras/Projects/UI/Main.qml)::importExtension: loaded "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Window.2/qmldir"                                                                             [:0]
[DBG  | default] QQmlImportDatabase::registerPluginTypes: "QtQuick.Window" from "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Window.2"                       [:0]
[DBG  | default] QQmlImports(file:///home/aras/Projects/UI/Main.qml)::addFileImport: "sysui" -1.-1 as ""                                              [:0]
[DBG  | default] QQmlImports(file:///home/aras/Projects/UI/Main.qml)::addLibraryImport: "controls" 1.0 as ""                                          [:0]
[DBG  | default] QQmlImports(file:///home/aras/Projects/UI/Main.qml)::importExtension: loaded "/home/aras/Projects/UI/imports/shared/controls/qmldir"                                                                            [:0]
[DBG  | default] QQmlImports(file:///home/aras/Projects/UI/Main.qml)::addLibraryImport: "utils" 1.0 as ""                                             [:0]
[DBG  | default] QQmlImports(file:///home/aras/Projects/UI/Main.qml)::importExtension: loaded "/home/aras/Projects/UI/imports/shared/utils/qmldir"                                                                               [:0]
[WARN | default] QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component            [:0]
[WARN | default] file:///home/aras/Projects/UI/Main.qml:6 module "Qt3D.Core" is not installed
                                                                           [:0]
[CRIT | am.system] ERROR: Qml scene does not have a root object            [:0]
```

Qt is installed in `/usr/local/Qt-5.7.0`:

```
$ which qml
/usr/local/Qt-5.7.0/bin//qml
aras@aras-T900:~$ which qmake
/usr/local/Qt-5.7.0/bin//qmake
```

Inside my `.qml` file I attempt to import the 3D libraries I need:

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
```

Yet, when I try to run my application, I get these errors:

```
...module "Qt3D.Render" is not installed
...module "Qt3D.Core" is not installed
```

I thought that is all I needed to do. What am I missing here?

Comment: "I have set the $QML2_IMPORT_PATH to the include directory inside my Qt installation" that's definitely wrong -- QML import paths have nothing to do with C++ includes. Moreover, you're not supposed to set that env variable it in order to find QML imports shipped with Qt. So just leave it unset.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Can you tell me how and where I am supposed to set that variable? Is it in the `project.pro` file? Several docs refer to that variable but do not say how to set it.

Comment: It's an environment variable, so you set it when you start your executable. If you're using Creator, in the Project pane (on the left), Run settings for a given kit (on the top), and alter the environment in there. But the whole point is that *you should not need to set it* for modules coming with Qt itself. If those modules are installed but not found, set instead the environment variable `QML_IMPORT_TRACE` to 1 and check that they're indeed found.

Comment: Ok I edit my post with the qml import trace output. I can not identify the problem. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Where is your version of Qt installed?

Comment: Qt is installed in `/usr/local/Qt-5.7.0`: 
`$ which qml
/usr/local/Qt-5.7.0/bin//qml
aras@aras-T900:~$ which qmake
/usr/local/Qt-5.7.0/bin//qmake`

Comment: Is it right to say that if I did things correctly there should be a `QQmlImports` call for Qt3D.Core ?

Comment: The imports in the trace file are totally wrong, however. Note how `/usr/local/Qt-5.7.0/include` gets added (**it does not belong there!** it's a path for C++ includes, not QML modules! check your environment variables!), and also `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml`, which looks like a system wide installation of Qt, possibly coming from your distribution. Your application is picking up stuff from that system wide installation, which is definitely wrong. Are you using `qml` to run your application? Is there anything at all set in the `QML_IMPORT_PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Did you solve this? If yes..how?

Comment: Jiloc: I add an answer with my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got 3D working in my qt app by checking out the latest source code from qt and building it. Then when I ran into missing module problems, I build the corresponding module. In the case of 3D, this is what I did:

```
cd qt3d
../qtbase/bin/qmake ../../qt5/qt3d
make -j5
```

This is assuming an out of source directory build. Source code is inside `qt5` directory. Hope this helps someone.